# Implementation of std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>> for C++20

Tags: c++, pointers, atomic

As you may know, C++20 has added `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` specialization to the standard, but sadly, most compilers have not implemented it yet. So I decided to implement it myself.

I want to know if I can improve this code or not. In addition, I'm not sure if my implementations of `wait()`, `notify_one()` and `notify_all()` are correct using condition variable.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <version>

#if !defined(__cpp_lib_atomic_shared_ptr) || (__cpp_lib_atomic_shared_ptr == 0)

namespace std {

template<typename T> 
struct atomic<shared_ptr<T>> {

    using value_type = shared_ptr<T>;

    static constexpr bool is_always_lock_free = false;
    bool is_lock_free() const noexcept {
        return false;
    }

    constexpr atomic() noexcept {};
    atomic(shared_ptr<T> desired) noexcept : ptr_(std::move(desired)) {};
    atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
    void operator=(const atomic&) = delete;

    void store(shared_ptr<T> desired, memory_order order = memory_order::seq_cst) noexcept {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m_);
        atomic_store_explicit(&ptr_, std::move(desired), order);
    }
    void operator=(shared_ptr<T> desired) noexcept {
        store(std::move(desired));
    }

    shared_ptr<T> load(memory_order order = memory_order::seq_cst) const noexcept {
        return atomic_load_explicit(&ptr_, order);
    }
    operator shared_ptr<T>() const noexcept {
        return load();
    }

    shared_ptr<T> exchange(shared_ptr<T> desired, memory_order order = memory_order::seq_cst) noexcept {
        return atomic_exchange_explicit(&ptr_, std::move(desired), order);
    }

    bool compare_exchange_weak(shared_ptr<T>& expected, shared_ptr<T> desired,
                                memory_order success, memory_order failure) noexcept {
        return atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(&ptr_, &expected, std::move(desired), success, failure);
    }
    bool compare_exchange_strong(shared_ptr<T>& expected, shared_ptr<T> desired,
                                    memory_order success, memory_order failure) noexcept {
        return atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&ptr_, &expected, std::move(desired), success, failure);
    }
    bool compare_exchange_weak(shared_ptr<T>& expected, shared_ptr<T> desired,
                                memory_order order = memory_order::seq_cst) noexcept {
        return compare_exchange_weak(expected, std::move(desired), order, convert_order(order));
    }
    bool compare_exchange_strong(shared_ptr<T>& expected, shared_ptr<T> desired,
                                    memory_order order = memory_order::seq_cst) noexcept {
        return compare_exchange_strong(expected, std::move(desired), order, convert_order(order));
    }

    void wait(shared_ptr<T> old, memory_order order = memory_order::seq_cst) const noexcept {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m_);
        cv_.wait(lk, [&]{ return !(load(order) == old); });
    }
    void notify_one() noexcept {
        cv_.notify_one();
    }
    void notify_all() noexcept {
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

private:
    shared_ptr<T> ptr_;
    mutable std::condition_variable cv_;
    mutable std::mutex cv_m_;

    constexpr memory_order convert_order(memory_order order) {
        switch(order) {
        case std::memory_order_acq_rel:
            return std::memory_order_acquire;
        
        case  std::memory_order_release:
            return std::memory_order_relaxed;

        default:
            return order;
        }
    }
};

}

#endif

int main() {
    std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<int>> a;
}
```

I will be happy about your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple things:

- `operator=` <del>should</del> would normally return `*this` rather than `void`:

  ```
  atomic& operator=(value_type desired) noexcept {
      store(std::move(desired));
      return *this;
  }
  ```

  But it seems that the standard actually requires `void` return here, so the implementation is correct.
- Default construction should initialize members:

  ```
  private:
      value_type ptr_= {};
      mutable std::condition_variable cv_ = {};
      mutable std::mutex cv_m_= {};
  ```
- Since we're writing for C++20, we can take advantage of [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to simplify, e.g.

  ```
      std::lock_guard lk{cv_m_};
  ```

---

I don't like the name of `convert_order()`.  I might call it something like `order_without_release()`, to be more specific about *why* it's used.  Yes, it's a private function, but it's still important to keep it clear.

Similarly, I'd name the `success` and `failure` arguments more explicitly - perhaps `success_mem_order` etc.?

I think that `convert_order` ought to be `constexpr static`, since it doesn't use `*this`.

---

Our implementation is not lock-free:

> ```
> static constexpr bool is_always_lock_free = false;
> bool is_lock_free() const noexcept {
>     return false;
> }
> ```

A library implementation with access to internals of shared-pointer might be able to avoid that, but we can't.  Still, it's better than no implementation at all.

---

Otherwise, this looks pretty good.  We should be able to use a very similar implementation to provide `std::shared_ptr<std::weak_ptr<T>>`, too.

Comment: I really don't know why I have messed up first 2 points.... <.<

Comment: I just remembered why my `operator=` returns `void`. because I copied template of this class from standard: https://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.atomic.shared in addition, in cpp ref it also returns `void`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2

Comment: Ah, interesting.  And the non-specialised `std::atomic` returns [a copy of the stored value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator%3D).  I'm not sure why.

Comment: @TobySpeight, my expectation would be that the value returned from = is exactly the same used for assignment itself. Since atomics can change between any atomic operations, I guess returning a copy would lead to less bugs that are extremely hard to reproduce.

Comment: I think because if `operator=` for this specialization returns a copy, internal `shared_ptr`'s reference count should be increased which is not logical. Then they probably decided to use `void` returning function.